# Listing dependencies in package.xml that are also dependency of dependency

Tags: ros, ros2, package.xml, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested in hearing about best practice of listing a dependency in package.xml that is already a dependency of another dependency.

Let's say I have two packages:

- `foo_interfaces` - with a dependency on `builtin_interfaces`
- `foo_core` - with a dependency on `foo_interfaces`

In `foo_core`, I fill out a message defined in `foo_interfaces`, and in doing so, I `import builtin_interfaces`. So, a file in `foo_core` would look like this for example:

```
import builtin_interfaces
import foo_interfaces

bar = foo_interfaces.msg.Bar()
bar.header.stamp = builtin_interfaces.msg.Time()
```

In this case, `builtin_interfaces` is a dependency of `foo_interfaces`, so it should be available as long as `foo_core` depends on `foo_interfaces`. So, having `builtin_interfaces` in foo_core's package.xml would be redundant.

Is it better practice to add `builtin_interfaces` to `foo_core`'s package.xml, and why (or not) would that be better?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405832/listing-dependencies-in-package.xml-that-are-also-dependency-of-dependency/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2022-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are basically asking how to deal with *transitive* dependencies (or whether you could benefit from them in any way), and this is not necessarily specific to ROS, nor to any programming language.

(I'm not saying this because I believe your question is off-topic for this website. I'm just trying to clarify what I'm writing below is not specific to ROS, how it manages dependencies or which particular programming language is being used)

> Is it better practice to add `builtin_interfaces` to `foo_core`'s package.xml, and why (or not) would that be better?

In almost all cases I've heard and seen this discussed, the rule is: explicitly declare a dependency on everything you directly `#include`, `import` or whatever the specific idiom in the language you're using is.

Rationale: if, in your example, `foo_interfaces` ever removes or changes its dependency on `builtin_interfaces`, and `foo_core` doesn't declare that dependency itself, `foo_core` now has a problem, as there's nothing bringing in that dependency any more.

A different way of thinking about this is: it is `foo_core`'s responsibility to make sure it has access to *its* dependencies. It's not `foo_interfaces`' responsibility to keep track of those. `foo_interfaces`' responsibility is to keep track of its own dependencies.

Yet another way: the fact `foo_interfaces` depends on `builtin_interfaces` is an *implementation detail* of `foo_interfaces`, and not something you should make assumptions about in `foo_core`. If you do, you're increasing coupling between these packages unnecessarily, which *not* `a-good-thing` to do in a component based system.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-09-01**:
There is some nuance to be added which comes down to which parts of `foo_interfaces` could be considered part of its public API when it comes to dependencies and changing them, but in general I believe what I write here also holds for messages, services and actions.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-09-01**:
Yeah there's always nuances, but the primary thing that should drive the logic is that if no one else depends on it and your code will break you should have a dependency on it.

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-09-01**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn!